# 301 redirect to a new link in the website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hello i want to redirect the following url

```
example.com/2015/07/new-post.html
```

to

```
example.com/2015/07/new-post/
```

Thanks in advance.

**Found a working solution**

to change the extension from html to php

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.example.com$1.php
```

to simply remove .html extension from url

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ $1
```

And godaddy users have to add the following code in the beginning

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*).html /$1.php [R=301,L]

Comment: Yes Godaddy is an enormous pain with hosting and don't recommend their setup.